# Adding eventListeners to checkboxes in for loop in chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a function that gets all the tabs in a window and then updates the popup.html page by adding a checkbox for each tab.  After doing this there is a second for loop that adds event listeners which update an dictionary containing the value of the checkbox's.  The problem is that any checkbox I click only updates the last element in the dictionary.

Here is the code:

```
function viewTabs() {
  var queryInfo = {lastFocusedWindow: true};
  // Go through all the tabs open, and add them to the scrollview along with a number and checkbox
  chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    document.getElementById("openLinks").innerHTML = "";
    (function() {
      for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        // add checkboxes to each link for the user to include or disclude
        document.getElementById("openLinks").innerHTML += 
            "<li><input type=\"checkbox\" id = \"" + i.toString() + "\" checked>" + 
            tabs[i].title + "</li>";
        checkedTabsArr[i.toString()] = true;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i.toString()).addEventListener("click",
          function() {
            console.log(checkedTabsArr);
            checkedTabsArr[i.toString()] = !checkedTabsArr[i.toString()];
        });
      }
    }());
  });
}
```

Here is the output (I am clicking different checkboxes not just 6):

```
Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: false}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: false}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: false}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true}
Buttons.js:174 Object {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: false}
```

I have tried with and without closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using two separate for loops inside the same context?

**EDIT**
I've tracked this down to an issue with how javascript handles both click and change events with checkboxes.

Note: Don't ever use click events for checkboxes, use `onChange` instead. Also, don't assign `onchange` using javascript. It fails spectacularly for some reason that I can't identify.

Instead, use jQuery for it.
Make sure you have the jQuery library included on your page and load your script after all DOM elements are loaded on the page. Then this code should work for you just fine:

```
function viewTabs() {
    var queryInfo = {
        lastFocusedWindow: true
    };

    // Go through all the tabs open, and add them to the scrollview along with a number and checkbox
    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {

        for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            var thisTab = tabs[i];

            // add checkboxes to each link for the user to include or disclude
            // start by creating a blank checkbox element
            var thisCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
            thisCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
            thisCheckbox.id = i;
            thisCheckbox.checked = true;

            //Add the event listener to the newly created checkbox
            attachChangeListener(thisCheckbox, i);
            console.log(thisCheckbox);

            // create a blank <li>
            var thisListItem = document.createElement('li');

            // add the checkbox and tab title to <li>
            thisListItem.appendChild(thisCheckbox);
            thisListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(thisTab.title));

            // add <li> to the end of the openLinks element and add a new value to the array
            document.getElementById("openLinks").appendChild(thisListItem);
            checkedTabsArr[i] = true;

            console.log(tabs[i].title + ": " + thisCheckbox.checked);

        }

        function toggle(checkbox, title) {
            console.log("CLICK EVENT FOR: " + title);

            //toggle the state of the checkbox
            checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
            console.log(title + " updated: " + checkbox.checked);


        }

        function attachChangeListener(element, index) {
            $(element).change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    //match the array's value to that of the new checkbox state
                    checkedTabsArr[index] = true;
                    console.log(checkedTabsArr);
                } else {
                    //match the array's value to that of the new checkbox state
                    checkedTabsArr[index] = false;
                    console.log(checkedTabsArr);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The above code should hopefully be a plug and play solution for you.

Let me know how this goes for you.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wof8ebq7/27/

Comment: I just tested it.  The problem now is that when I click the checkboxes nothing happens.  I added a console.log statement, but nothing happens when a checkbox is clicked

Comment: that fixed the problem, but why?  Was it because you used jquery?

Comment: Yes. I'm also not sure the "why" behind this, but if you search stack overflow, you'll find of BUNCH of cases where using javascript to attach click or change listeners to a checkbox just fails miserably.
For some reason, the event will trigger the moment it is instantiated (both before and after DOM ready) and then promptly delete itself.

This doesn't happen if you use jQuery though so the standing solution is to attach the `change` event listener using jQuery.

Glad to see that worked for you.